# Heap Corruption Detected after Normal block (#155) in C

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I have a piece of code like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char array[10000];
    char *newArray=NULL;
    int j=0;
    int k;
    while(gets_s(array))
    {
       int length=strlen(array);
       newArray=(char *)realloc(NULL,length*sizeof(char));
       for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
           if(array[i]==' '||i==0)
           {
               if(i==0)
                   i--;
               k=i+1;
               while(array[k]!=NULL&&array[k]!=' ')
               {
                   newArray[j++]=array[k++];
               }
               newArray[j++]=' ';
           }
       }
       newArray[j]='\0';
       printf(newArray);
       free(newArray);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is that I want to reverse the string as I continuously input the string.

For example, I input: "this is a dog", the result will return: "dog a is this", and I want to continue to input another string and found the error:

```
"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#155) at 0x004CAF38
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Does your `j` get reset with each iteration?  (It doesn't seem so …)

Comment: Well have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I see a problem... I just can't put my finger on it...

Comment: @awesomeyi: The title said C; the `using namespace std;` said C++; the cast on `realloc()` suggests C++.  I suspect it is C being compiled with a C++ compiler.  I see the OP removed the use of `cout` and `<iostream>`.  It is confused/confusing.

Comment: Try using > and < instead of <= or, really that looks strange. Also try +1 to the "length."

Comment: This call of `gets_s` is illegal, your compiler should give error. (Possibly it says "warning" but they are errors). Make sure you have a warning-free compile before trying to run.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You'll no-doubt not be shocked to know that MS can be likely thanked for that: `template <size_t size> char *gets_s(char (&buffer)[size]);` It would seem the OP's original code included C++ headers and was not a mistake. For *real* C11 compliance, you're clearly correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the info! So this is really a C++ question , if OP does not get errors. Actually checking the edit history it was clearly a C++ question but Jonathan changed it to C >.>

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. On the off-chance you're still watching your question, one way is a recursive algorithm. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/wVh01p). A good challenge is to think of yet-more ways to accomplish the same task. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory in your newarray to allot for the end of string terminating character:

```
newArray=(char *)realloc(NULL,length*sizeof(char));
```

Later you are setting:

```
newArray[j]='\0';
```

where j exceeds the memory size by 1.

Change to:

```
newArray=(char *)realloc(NULL,length*sizeof(char) + 1);
```

and

```
  newArray[j-1]='\0'
```

Also need to reset j.

Comment: or `newArray = malloc(length + 1);`